# Как отправить два email, используя функцию mail()

Tags: php, email

Я пытаюсь отправить два различных письма функцией `mail`, используя следующий код:

```
mail ($email_one,$theme_one,$message_one,"Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8");

mail ($email_two,$theme_two,$message_two,"Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

Но письмо приходит только первому получателю. Как отправить письма обоим получателям, учитывая, что текст писем отличается?

Comment: Полагаю, на хостинге стоит ограничение на минимальный интервал между отправками писем.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй сделать паузу между отправками, на хостингах часто стоят ограничения, чтобы запретить спам-рассылки.

Если не получится, можно отправлять письма другими сервисами.